# Detect key pressed in python not working

Tags: python, keyboard, key, python-multithreading, msvcrt

```
import pyautogui, time, threading, keyboard, msvcrt

global active, exitp
active = False
exitp = False

Names = []

def mainLoop():
    global active, exitp
    pressedkey = msvcrt.getch()
    while True:
         if pressedkey == 'z':
            active = not active
         elif pressedkey == 'x':
            exitp = False
            break

def running():
    global exitp
    while not exitp:
        print("Running")
        time.sleep(3)

start = time.time()
print("Your screen size is: " + str(pyautogui.size()))
width, height = pyautogui.size()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=mainLoop, args=())
t2 = threading.Thread(target=running, args=())
t1.start()
t2.start()
while not exitp:
    if active:
        pyautogui.click(90, height - 110)
        for i in range(len(Names)):
            if active:
                pyautogui.typewrite(Names)
                pyautogui.press("enter")
            else:
                break
        active = False
end = time.time()
print("Execution time: " + str(end-start) + " seconds")
```

trying to make a loop that exits when i press 'x', and types/stops typing  names from my array called "Names" when pressing 'z', however, i'm pressing both 'x' and 'z' but they don't anything, help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pynput import keyboard

import pyautogui
import threading
import sys

class Status:
    _exit = False
    active = True

names = [str(i) for i in range(0, 10, 1)]

width, height = pyautogui.size()

def mainThread():
    listenerThread = keyboard.Listener(on_press = onKeyPress)
    listenerThread.start()

    while(not Status._exit):
        if (not Status.active):
            continue

        pyautogui.click(90, height - 110)

        for i in range(len(names)):
            if (not Status.active or Status._exit):
                break

            pyautogui.typewrite(names[i])
            pyautogui.press("enter")


    keyboard.Listener.stop(listenerThread)
    print("Stopped listerning")
    sys.exit(0)


def onKeyPress(key):
    print("Still listerning")

    try:
        k = key.char
    except Exception:
        k = key.name

    if (k == "z"):
        Status.active = not Status.active

    elif (k == "x"):
        Status._exit = not Status._exit


#controlThread = threading.Thread(target = mainThread)
#controlThread.start()

mainThread()
```

Instead of using globals I used a 'static' class which stored the status. I also used a different module to listen to key inputs.

I think this is what you wanted.

EDIT: You don't have to have the main loop as a thread. If you wanted to do other things then set it as a thread (uncomment the two lines and comment the last line) or just leave it how it is.

Comment: That wasn't what i originally wanted, but your code helped me understand what i did wrong, Thank you!